# Unit testing a method having parameter of interface type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit

I have the following code:

```
public BooksInfo GetBookInfo(IBookMarket bookinfo)
{
    // Implementation omitted
}
```

I can only post the method signature. Now I need to pass a null value as `bookinfo` and test whether exception is raised or not.

Can someone explain briefly how can I do this unit test using NUnit?

**Edit Question:**

***My Unit Test Code***

```
[TestFixture]

public class FutureTests
{
    //[Test]
    //[ExpectedException(typeof(NullReferenceException),
    // ExpectedMessage = "No value provided!")]
    public void GetPriceData_PassNull_ThrowsException()
    {
        Assert.That(
                () => library.GetPriceData(null),
                Throws.InstanceOf<ArgumentNullException>()
                .With.Property("").EqualTo("pricer"));

    }
}
```

Comment: @joao I have posted. this is my unit test code.

Comment: You should not be passing an empty string, you should use `Property("ParamName")` if you want to get the value of the `ParamName` property of the exception.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo yeah i changed and checked but showing same error

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibitities provided by [nunit](/questions/tagged/nunit):

### Old style

Pre 2.X implementation

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestGetBookInfo
{
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(
        ExpectedException = typeof(YourException),
        ExpectedMessage = "Your detailed message",
        MatchType = MessageMatch.Contains)]
    public void TestGetBookInfoException()
    {
        new BookInfoProvider().GetBookInfo(null);
    }
}
```

### New style

Current fluent implementation

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestGetBookInfo
{
    [Test]
    public void TestGetBookInfo()
    {
        Assert.That(
            () => new BookInfoProvider().GetBookInfo(null),
                Throws.InstanceOf<YourException>()
                    .And.Message.Contains("Your detailed message"));
    }
}
```

### Data driven

Data driven implementation where you could combine cases

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestGetBookInfo
{
    object[] TestData =
    {
        new TestCaseData(new BookMarketStub()), // "good" case
        new TestCaseData(null).Throws(typeof(YourException)) // "bad" exceptional case
    };

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("TestData")]
    public void TestGetBookInfo(IBookMarket bookinfo)
    {
        new BookInfoProvider().GetBookInfo(bookinfo);
        Assert.Pass("all ok"); // this is not necessary
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the "BookInfoProvider" you have mentioned in code below New Style. Let me know that.

Comment: I can't find name of type that contains `GetBookInfo` method, so I named it `BookInfoProvider`. In your sample variable `library` is of `GetBookInfo` type.

Comment: what is "BookMarketStub"? what is the purpose and how to create? let me know.till now i did not get a solution for my doubt. I am trying ways mentioned in all answers but finding errors.

Comment: `BookMarketStub` is stub implementation of `IBookMarket` used as default value for tests. Here is a full working sample that contains all previous samples: http://pastebin.com/E7efgcdc

Comment: i have tried, but problem is BookInfoProvider.GetBookInfo() here i am not getting GetBookInfo in intellisense. in one way its saying lambda expression error and in other way invalid argument.

Comment: sure, but you should know difference: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Answer (score 3):

Using NUnit I would go with:

```
Assert.That(
    () => library.GetBookInfo(null),
    Throws.InstanceOf<ArgumentNullException>());
```

This code assumes that `library` is an instance of the type that defined your `GetBookInfo` method. **Also, this approach has considerable advantage over the `ExpectedException` alternative because it asserts that is really the code under test that is throwing an exception and not the test itself**.

It verifies that the method throws an `ArgumentNullException` because that's the correct exception to throw when you validate a required parameter and it is a null reference. The `NullReferenceException` should not be thrown programatically by user code.

In this case where the method has only one parameter this may be omitted, but if you want to improve even further your test you could assert that the exception is associated with the parameter in question by doing this:

```
Assert.That(
    () => library.GetBookInfo(null),
    Throws.InstanceOf<ArgumentNullException>()
        .With.Property("ParamName").EqualTo("bookinfo"));
```

With this extra assertion your test guarantees that the code is implemented like this (as it should):

```
public BooksInfo GetBookInfo(IBookMarket bookinfo)
{
    if (bookinfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bookinfo");

    // Implementation omitted
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining why one approach has advantage over another.

Comment: @joao at the line library.getbookinfo, i am getting an error showing "Cannot convert lambda expression to type bool because it is not a delegate type".

Comment: @joao "ParamName" and "bookinfo" are same right? if not what is "ParamName" you have mentioned over there?

Comment: The `ParamName` is a property in the `ArgumenNullException` type that indicates the parameter associated with the exception. Are you still getting the error on your previous comment, if yes, can you post the full code of your unit test?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[Test]
public void myTest
{
    try
    {
       // Hier you call your methode GetBookInfo(null)
       Assert.True(false);
    }
    Catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }    
}
```

Alternativly you can set an ExpectedException Attribute to your test like:

```
[Test ExpectedException( typeof( NullReferenceException) )]
public void myTest
{
    //Just Call the Methode which should throw an exception
}
```